# How can i get the members of a Dropbox shared folder programmatically using c#?

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropnet

I want to get or find all the members of a shared folder from a Dropbox account. Currently I'm using DropNet, but there is no such option i found.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does not currently have any way to programmatically get a list of shared folder members.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spring Social dropbox framework](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-dropbox)  for .Net. They have already provided some examples in it. In one of the example they have provided the code for listing all files for a particular type.

Additional Code:

```
//After creating dropbox service use the following code 
//Following code searches the root folder, file of type "all" including subfolders
//To search a particular folder write the path in the first parameter of SearchAsync Method
//To list only "txt" files write ".txt" for the second parameter
```

```
dropbox.SearchAsync("", ".").ContinueWith(task =>
{                    
Console.WriteLine(task.Result.Count);
    foreach (Entry file in task.Result)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(file.Path); //prints path
    }
});
```